# Unique, Unordered Sets from Collection of Elements (Power set)

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

I've lost most of my Friday to trying to solve this problem:

**Generate a list of unique, unorderd sets from a collection of integers.**

*[If an element is repeated in the original collection, it is to be considered two separate elements for the purposes of building the sets]*

I eventually arrived at the following, which achieves the correct results. I am wondering if there is a more efficient method.

In particular, my Shift() method must exist somewhere in a more efficient form. I am not very familiar with bitwise operations... but perhaps they apply here?

```
    List<int[]> Unique(List<int> intList)
    {
        List<int[]> results = new List<int[]>();

        bool[] toAdd = new bool[intList.Count];
        toAdd[toAdd.Length - 1] = true;

        int totalSets = (int)Math.Pow(2, intList.Count) - 1;

        List<int[]> sets = new List<int[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSets; i++)
        {
            int[] set = new int[toAdd.Count(p => p)];
            int c = 0;
            for (int j = toAdd.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                if (toAdd[j])
                    set[c++] = intList[j];

            Shift(toAdd);
            results.Add(set);
        }

        return results;
    }

    void Shift(bool[] array)        
    {
        bool doShift = true;
        for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (doShift) 
                array[i] = !array[i];
            doShift = (doShift && !array[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just so we're on the same page, you're looking for the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), right? So for [1,2,3] you get {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}?

Comment: Yes, less the empty set, and why my total solution set count is (2^n) - 1. Also why the bit array starts at 1 rather than 0.

Comment: In that case, it looks fine as far as complexity goes, assuming nobody has a wizardly way to generate sets in sub-Θ(n) amortized time. As for constant factors, I'll defer to people who actually know C#.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, the time complexity will always be O(2^n) so you the best you can hope for are constant time improvements. That said, your implementation can be simplified to the following:

```
public static List<int[]> powerSetBit(int[] list) {
    if (list == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list may not be null.");

    if (list.Length > 31)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("list must have 31 or fewer items.");

    List<int[]> results = new List<int[]>();

    int count = 1 << list.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int subsetSize = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < list.Length && (1 << j) < count; j++)
            if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0)
                subsetSize++;

        int[] subset = new int[subsetSize];
        for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < list.Length && (1 << j) < count; j++)
            if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0)
                subset[k++] = list[j];

        results.Add(subset);
    }

    return results;
}
```

For an input size of about 20 items, the existing implementation takes about 771 milliseconds on average to execute on my machine and the simplified implementation takes about 513 milliseconds to execute on average on my machine.

If your goal is to improve the readability of the implementation you can also go with the recursive implementation which is slightly slower (857 milliseconds on average for the example test case).

The recursive solution works by observing that the list is an element of the power set and that each power set of the list less one of its elements is also part of the overall power set. To prevent duplicated sets, only the left hand side of the traversal tree is considered through the use of the second argument.

```
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        List<List<int>> lists = powerSet(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        foreach (List<int> list in lists)
            Console.WriteLine("{{{0}}}", String.Join(", ", list));
    }

    public static List<List<int>> powerSet(List<int> list) {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list may not be null.");

        return powerSet(list, list.Count);
    }

    public static List<List<int>> powerSet(List<int> list, int j) {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list may not be null.");

        if (j < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("j must be not be negative.");

        List<List<int>> results = new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>(list) };

        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) { 
            int x = list[i];
            list.RemoveAt(i);
            results.AddRange(powerSet(list, i));
            list.Insert(i, x);
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each of the element in the original array are considered unique even when they have the same value, the problem can be treated in this way: For each element in the array, you have two choices: including it or not including it in the set. Therefore each element doubles the number of solutions, resulting the overall number of solutions: 2 * 2 * 2 ... * 2 - 1 = 2^n - 1. Minus one is because you are excluding empty set from the solutions. Since the number of solutions is 2^n - 1, the complexity of your algorithm cannot be better than O(2^n). The only improvement you can do is probably write the algorithm in a way that is more compact or easier to understand.

I have the following code that I think is more straightforward. I have not tested so there might be bugs.

```
// Generate unique sets in the range [k..n) of the input arr. With elements
// from [0..k) already in the prefix.
void Unique(int[] arr, int k, List<int> prefix, List<int[]> solutions)
{
    // Got a solution when we reached the end of array.
    if (k == arr.Length)
    {
        if (prefix.Length > 0)
            solutions.Add(prefix.ToArray());
        return;
    }

    // Exclude arr[k]
    Unique(arr, k + 1, prefix, solutions);

    // Include arr[k]
    prefix.Add(arr[k]);
    Unique(arr, k + 1, prefix, solutions);
    prefix.Remove(arr[k]); // Restore the prefix list
}

List<int[]> Unique(int[] arr)
{
    List<int[]> solutions = new List<int[]>();
    Unique(arr, 0, new List<int>(), List<int[]> solutions);
    return solutions;
}
```